CRA/webpack production error: t[s] is not a function
I'm getting this strange error in a React CRA app in production builds only:
bootstrap:19 Uncaught TypeError: t[s] is not a function
    at i (bootstrap:19:22)
    at Game.ts:142:3
    at index.tsx:19:25

Clicking on the first line of the stack trace takes me to webpack's bootstrap.js file:
// The module cache
var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};

// The require function
function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
    // Check if module is in cache
    var cachedModule = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId];
    if (cachedModule !== undefined) {
        return cachedModule.exports;
    }
    // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    var module = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId] = {
        // no module.id needed
        // no module.loaded needed
        exports: {}
    };
    
    // ERROR ON THIS LINE
    // Execute the module function
    __webpack_modules__[moduleId](module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

    // Return the exports of the module
    return module.exports;
}

// expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
__webpack_require__.m = __webpack_modules__;

The error is showing that moduleId does not exist in __webpack_modules__. I set a breakpoint on this line and it's erroring on moduleId=579. I'm not sure how to figure out what module that is to see what the bad package is. Is there a better way to debug this?
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "cosmicwar-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@bufbuild/protobuf": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.106",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "excalibur": "^0.29.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "ts-proto": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yaml": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "proto": "protoc --experimental_allow_proto3_optional --plugin=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts_proto.cmd --ts_proto_out=src/game/proto --proto_path ../proto-schema ../proto-schema/messages.proto",
    "configure": "xcopy /sy \"../data\" \"./public/data\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.12"
  }
}

Edit: Further debugging confirms that this error is coming from the main bundle during module initialization. Specifically, here:
function i(s) {
    var n = e[s];
    if (void 0 !== n)
        return n.exports;
    var r = e[s] = {
        exports: {}
    };
    console.log(t, s); // Added log for debugging
    return t[s](r, r.exports, i),
    r.exports
}

This log shows that t contains a map of module IDs to module functions. s is the module ID it's trying to run but it doesn't exist in t. Is there a way to find out what module this is? It is ID 579.
The other two lines of the stack trace, Game.ts:142:3 and index.tsx:19:25 is just pointing at the very end of the file. If I add more code to the end of either of these files, the error just moves to the end of the new code.
Edit 2: I've determined that the problem is the excalibur package. If I remove that import and all code using it, the error is gone.

What on Game.ts:142:3?

@Arkellys  It's pointing at the very end of the Game class. The error seems to be happening at declaration time because a console.log in its constructor does not fire. So the class isn't even getting instantiated yet. Again, this error is happening on production build only, not in dev mode.

If you delete package lock and node_modules and run npm install, does it give the same result in dev and production?

@qrsngky I have tried that already yes, same results. I've also tried switching to yarn, also no change.

I would say to try to replace whatever is on Game.ts with some dummy code and see if you still have the problem. If it's in the stack of the error then the problem must come from here. I don't see how we can help you with just the info you provided.

@Arkellys I honestly don't think that's relevant given my debugging so far. When I step through the code, I can clearly see the error is happening during initial module loading. None of my actual code runs yet. No matter where I put a log, nothing shows unless it's at the top-level. The Game class is being used within my App.tsx, and that last error in index.tsx is the reportWebVitals() line. If I remove that then the error in that file just moves up to the <App/> line.

Additional debug info added in post

@chrispytoes Alright, then I suggest to use the dumb debug steps: you remove 99% of the code of your app, test if it works, and if it does, put back the code piece by piece till it breaks. If it breaks even when most of your code is gone and you just have a "Hello World" app, then something's wrong with your config.

@Arkellys I've determined that the problem is the Excalibur.js game engine I'm using. If I remove that import and all code using it, it works without error. So what do I do from here? It's Create React App so all the webpack configuration is internal. I could eject the configs but I still wouldn't know what to even change there.

Good job. If you can create a minimal reproductible example as gist or repo, I could try to tweak the config and see if I find a solution. Otherwise, you can try to compare react-scripts config with excalibur webpack template to see what could be different. You can use craco or react-app-rewired to override your config without ejecting (but it's a bit trickier)

I found that the "579" is related to react, as it's used in return(0,h.jsx) [or similar] in the main.[something].js of the output.
And after some investigation, I have identified the main cause of the problem: in node_modules/excalibur/build/esm/excalibur.js there is var __webpack_modules__ = . If you replace the 2 instances of __webpack_modules__ in that file with another variable name, then the result of npm run build can run without the weird error.

Another way to avoid the problem is to go to node_modules/excalibur/package.json and change "module": "build/esm/excalibur.js", to "module": "build/esm/excalibur.min.js" (the variable name is changed due to minification, so it has no conflict with the __webpack_modules__  from the CRA). But ultimately, the package authors should update the package.

@qrsngky Thank you!!! Please, if you could put that in an answer I'll accept it. This will work for now, I just made an npm script to easily make that edit to the excalibur package.json automatically.

I found that the "579" is related to react, as it's used in return(0,h.jsx)(...) [or similar] in the main.[something].js of the build output.
And after some investigation, I have identified the main cause of the problem: in node_modules/excalibur/build/esm/excalibur.js there is var __webpack_modules__ = . If you replace the 2 instances of __webpack_modules__ in that file with another variable name, then the result of npm run build can run without the weird error.
Another way to avoid the problem is to go to node_modules/excalibur/package.json and change "module": "build/esm/excalibur.js", to "module": "build/esm/excalibur.min.js" (the variable name is changed due to minification, so it has no conflict with the __webpack_modules__ from the CRA).
But ultimately, the package authors should update the package. Otherwise, every time you run npm install you will need to edit the file(s).
